# Trouble with Promise in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I’m a beginner at React and I was recently going across this *asynchronous data* fetching and tried to simulate it by using Promise in the following code. (Data fetching takes time, so yes, I should use setTimeout() with Promise, but the code here is for simplicity.)

```
function List({stories})
{
    console.log("Hi from List");                 //Testing if component is rendered
    return(<>
        {
           stories.map(function(element)
           {
               return (<li>{element.title}</li>);
           })
        }
        </>);
}
```

```
function App()
{
    const stories=[
        {title:"Alice in Wonderland"},
        {title:"Beauty & the Beast"}
    ];

    const [newStories,setNewStories]=React.useState([]);

    function wait()
    {
        console.log("Check");                           //To see if code works here
        Promise.resolve({data:stories});
    }

    React.useEffect(function()
                {
                   wait().then(result=>setNewStories(result.data))
                },[]);

    return(
        <>
        <h1>{"Titles"}</h1>
        <hr/>
        <List stories={newStories}/>
        <hr/>
        </>
    );
}
```

The above code produces the desired output(only for half a second or so) and then immediately proceeds to give a white blank screen but when I replace the following it works perfectly.

```
React.useEffect(function()
                {
                Promise.resolve({data:stories}).then(result=>setNewStories(result.data))
            },[]);
```

Why is it not working when Promise is inside a function and why do I get this "Uncaught Type Error" for wait()?

(The code does print "Check" in the console, so why is it all of a sudden claiming the function to be undefined?)

---

I apparently have to put a return statement there.

Comment: There is no `return` from `wait`.

Comment: You are not returning any promise

Comment: @RakibUddin clearly no

Comment: @DeeTee You can use setTimeout with promise to see the difference clearly,
`return new Promise((res) => setTimeout(() => res({ data: stories }), 1000));`

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript Style

First, let me first show you a style guide to writing better JavaScript: *[Airbnb JavaScript Style Guide() {](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript)*

Writing good JavaScript code is essential so that your code is readable, not just by you but by everybody on Stack Overflow and the individuals you are working with.

- Curly braces should not be on its own new line
- Spaces should be used instead of tabulation characters
- Indent things correctly (using either 2 or 4 spaces)
- JSX should have an indented structure
- Don't indent randomly and whenever you feel like it, only when expected, and always when expected
- End-of-line comments should appear only 1 space away from the code

### ‍♀️ Promises

Promises are meant for asynchronous resolution. Example: if you are waiting for an event, such as a network request to come back with a response. This is because when creating a network request, a new thread is spun up so the rest of your JavaScript code can run instead of waiting for the response.

**Promises should not be used when simply returning a value.**

```js
// ✅ Good code
function wait() {
    return something
}

//  Bad code
function wait() {
    // (This is the correct way to write a Promise resolution)
    return new Promise(resolve => resolve(something));
}
```

Additionally, if you would like to write an asynchronous function that returns a promise, but you are not actually creating new threads, you want to use `async`/`await`:

```js
async function wait() {
    return something;
}
```

### ✅ Your Solution

The answer to your solution is simple. Your `wait` function does not return anything. Just creating a promise will not do anything, you have to return it.

```js
function wait() {
    return Promise.resolve(something);
}
```

Comment: Re *"Curly braces should not be on its own new line"*: Don't you mean the *opening* curly brace, `{` (not both of them)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen yes, sorry about the confusion. The ending curly braces should always be on it's own line, unless it precedes a parenthesis (like when passing a callback in an argument list) – or a similar situation.